# popViewController animated:YES not animating

Tags: ios, animation, viewwillappear

I have a download button in my view and when the button is clicked, the app opens the app store with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL]`
However when I switch back to my app, I find that the `[popViewController animated:YES]` in my app is not animating.
I debug it for a few days and solved the problem, the reason is that in my `applicationWillEnterForeground` method, i did this:

```
[tabBarController.selectedViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
```

AND I had the bug.
My question is, why after i invoked this method, all my `[popViewController animated:YES]` is not working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know exactly why you had that bug, but as Apple documentation, you **shouln't** call the `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method.

[UIViewController doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

It's a notification method, made to be **overriden**, and never called.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood well your question,but notice that the correct way to pop a viewncontroller is like this:

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

LUCKY